# Requested URL: /User/User/AddCustomer i am getting two controller name after clicking edit buuton and then after list button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

when i click edit button  it shows edit page   ..after that when i click to any  other  link button  it shows this error ----
Requested URL: /User/User/AddCustomer
The resource cannot be found

two controller name  user /user/view

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /User/User/EmployeeList

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

in url:http://localhost:2799/User/User/EmployeeList
u can see its getting  two controller

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve it.

Comment: Hi, yes please provide context, explain what you are trying to achieve so we can understand the origin of your issue. Sharing code is a good idea in most of the case

Comment: Please add the controller code and the view containing the control to your question so that we have more information to diagnose this issue

Comment: sir could You  tell me  why am i getting two controller name in url

Comment: i foud the solution

Answer (score 0):

layout

in Anchor tag   i paased link as a   href="../User/AddUser"

thats why i was getiing 
 two controller name

changed to href="~/User/AddUder"

tild '~' symbol

now its  working perfect

Thanks!!